# Implementing disqus on a php blogging website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, comments, disqus

I have this code to include in my php website but I keep getting this error: **We were unable to load Disqus. If you are a moderator please see our troubleshooting guide**. 
I have left trusted domains field empty in disqus dashboard to allow development on localhost.
The id is specific to each post.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var disqus_config = function () {
                var id = <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>;
                this.page.url = 'localhost/blog/viewimage.php?id='+id;
                this.page.identifier = id;
                };
                (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
                    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
                    s.src = 'https://ashexcreations.disqus.com/embed.js';
                    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
                    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
                })();
            </script>
```

Comment: try change `localhost` into `http://localhost`

Comment: *If you are a moderator please see our troubleshooting guide* - have you done so? What have you done to resolve the issue?

Comment: I appreciate the help plonknimbuzz. It worked.